# How install ubuntu-touch emulator on ubuntu13.10

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I  downloaded the emulator deb file:

`android_20131006-1510-0ubuntu6_all.deb` from launchpad

I then ran the command `dpkg -i android_20131006-1510-0ubuntu6_all.deb` to install it.

But i do not know how to run the emulator after installing finished.

I try running command `run-emulator.sh`, but terminal shows `no such command`, so what the exact command to run the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the directory through terminal and run the below command to execute `run-emulator.sh` file,

```
./run-emulator.sh
```

Comment: But in the directory "/usr/share/android/product/", there are only "*.img" files, no executable "*.sh" files.

Comment: where is run-emulator.sh file?

Comment: I donot know, but i didnot find it. Let me try to find again

Answer (score 0):

Add the PPA and install the emulator using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
```